# Set Object.prototype to null

Tags: javascript

In Crome console , I set Object.prototype = null, still I am able to invoke toString() method on newly created object.From where toString() method is coming ?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.prototype` is likely a special value that cannot be overridden.  Did you check the value of `Object.prototype` after setting it?  I'm willing to bet that your assignment didn't "stick."

Comment: Yes , My assignment did not work.I tried to do same with String.prototype and it also did not work.Can not we set the prototype of native java script constructors?If so then what is the rational behind it ?

Comment: @Gopal The browsers won't let you overwrite the value of  `Object.prototype`. The rationale behind it is simple: overwriting the prototype property of a native constructor is not reasonable in the first place.

Comment: That being said, you can augment `Object.prototype` with your own methods if you'd like.